# C# bouncycastle AsymmetricCipherKeyPair to byte array ECDSA

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I generate key pair like this.

```
ECKeyPairGenerator gen = new ECKeyPairGenerator("ECDSA");
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X9.X9ECParameters ecp = Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Nist.NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-256");
ECDomainParameters ecSpec = new ECDomainParameters(ecp.Curve, ecp.G, ecp.N, ecp.H, ecp.GetSeed());
ECKeyGenerationParameters ecgp = new ECKeyGenerationParameters(ecSpec, secureRandom);
gen.Init(ecgp);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair eckp = gen.GenerateKeyPair();
```

and I want to convert AsymmetricCipherKeyPair to byte array.

so I add code.

```
ECPublicKeyParameters ecPub = (ECPublicKeyParameters)eckp.Public;
ECPrivateKeyParameters ecPri = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)eckp.Private;
```

But I know there were two ways for convert AsymmetricCipherKeyPair to byte array.

first,

```
byte[] pubs = ecPub.Q.GetEncoded();
```

Second,

```
byte[] pubX = ecPub.Q.XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArray();
byte[] pubY = ecPub.Q.YCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArray();
```

The results of both methods are slightly different.

first way, pubs[0] is always 0x04, and it make array length to 65 bytes.
like this

```
04 F0 9E 70 EB ED 52 4B 56 E8 64 9C 9A D9 1C 97 6F F1 92 86 BA 87 FC F5 AB E4 CC 72 C6 EA 77 FA 0D 30 4C 39 0F 38 BE E3 C7 3E 8B 4D 2F 05 C3 55 3F 78 DB 8E DD 77 DF 24 D4 3B 56 88 33 D7 CB 0B 9E
```

seconde way, pubX[0] is sometimes 0x00, and it make array length to 65 bytes.

like this

```
pubX = 00 F0 9E 70 EB ED 52 4B 56 E8 64 9C 9A D9 1C 97 6F F1 92 86 BA 87 FC F5 AB E4 CC 72 C6 EA 77 FA 0D
pubY = 30 4C 39 0F 38 BE E3 C7 3E 8B 4D 2F 05 C3 55 3F 78 DB 8E DD 77 DF 24 D4 3B 56 88 33 D7 CB 0B 9E
```

Except for the value of index 0, the rest are the same.

Why does this difference occur?

What value do I actually use?

p.s.

I convert private key like this

```
byte[] pri = ecPri.D.ToByteArray();
```

Is this the right way?

And private key also has 0x00 on index 0. Why?

Comment: `GetEncoded()` returns the result in a "standard" format, suitable for exchanging with other software. Your other method serializes the components individually. As to which is right, that depends on what you want to do with these byte arrays.

Comment: Regarding `pubX`, `pubY` and `pri`: The sometimes occurring leading 0-byte is caused by `ToByteArray()`, which is used for a signed value and therefore takes the sign-bit into account. To avoid this effect, `ToByteArrayUnsigned()` can be used, which is better suited for an unsigned value. Regarding `pubs`: The leading `04` marks an _uncompressed_ EC-point representation, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48776).